# Where are the secret holes located?

Tags: ok-golf

Every course in OK Golf has two secret holes which can be unlocked by finding them while in Free Play mode. These can be hidden anywhere on a level, with some even being located out-of-bounds.

Which levels have secret holes? Where are they located?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a guide for the first 25 secret holes in OK Golf. Special thanks to the [Touch Arcade forums](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=301156) for helping find these.

---

## Secret hole locations in OK Golf.

### Secret Course

**Hole X (*To Cheat or Not to Cheat*)**

- Found on the Main Menu
- Go to the main menu, click the plus (**+**) in the top-left, and open the credits (**?**). Press "*Cheat to Unlock all courses*" to go to a secret, unmarked hole.

  [image: screenshot]

### Long Lake County • Georgia, USA

**Hole 10 (*The Winding Road*)**

- Found on the secret hole in the credits (*To Cheat or Not To Cheat*).
- On the fourth platform in the trees.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Are We There Yet?*)**

- Found on Hole 4.
- Out of bounds in the white void. To the right of the first bend in the fairway.

  [image: screenshot]

### Desert Canyon • Arizona, USA

**Hole 10 (*The Road Less Traveled*)**

- Found on Hole 3.
- Out of bounds in the void behind the green. Look across from the starting tee.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Nice View Up Here*)**

- Found on Hole 5.
- Out of bounds underneath the shadows of 2 small cacti on a hill to the right of the starting tee. This one is very hard to notice, even with screen brightness turned to max.

  [image: screenshot]

### Tsukimi Garden • Kyoto, Japan

**Hole 10 (*Long Way Round*)**

- Found on Hole 3.
- Out of bounds in the void behind the green.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Pond Life*)**

- Found on Pahoehoe Ridge Hole 10 (*Abandoned Course*)
- In the void behind the green to the right. I recommend chipping from the left, as it will make positioning the camera easier.

  [image: screenshot]

### Pahoehoe Ridge • Hawaii, USA

**Hole 10 (*Abandoned Course*)**

- Found on Hole 6.
- On top of a big rock in the central lake.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Beach Vacation*)**

- Found on Hole 10 (*Abandoned Course*).
- Out of bounds past the water on the small beach left of the starting tee. Hidden under the shadow of a rock-ledge.

  [image: screenshot]

### Buchan Bay • Aberdeen, Scotland

**Hole 10 (*Tightrope*)**

- Found on Hole 3.
- *Far* out of bounds behind the green. You will need a full power shot to reach it.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Fort Fore*)**

- Found on Hole 3.
- Hit the ball through the three windows with pink lilies to make the hole appear. These will appear near in the center of the hole by a Y-shaped set of walls and a tower.

  [image: screenshot]
- First hit the ball through the window frame with the lily in it. The screen should flash.
- Next hit it through the upper window on the section closest to the tower. The screen should flash.
- Next hit it through the big arch. The screen flashes again.
- A cup will appear off-course near the tee. Head back towards the tee and sink it.

  [image: screenshot]

### Miami Palms • Florida, USA

**Hole 10 (*Omega Golf*)**

- Found on Hole 9.
- In the rough on the peninsula of trees in the back-right of the level.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*The Wave*)**

- Found on Hole 10 (*Omega Golf*)
- Located behind the skyscraper on a small patch of rough.

  [image: screenshot]

### Oakford Woods • Somerset, England

**Hole 10 (*The Storm*)**

- Found on Hole 3
- Hit the ball towards the rock with the pink lily in the center of the map.

  [image: screenshot]
- After the screen flashes, hit the ball towards the rock that appears in the river.
- After the screen flashes, hit the ball towards the third rock that appears at the end of the river.
- The secret hole now appear past the river in the white out-of-bounds void.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*A Model Town*)**

- Found on Hole 4
- Hit the ball through the log pile in between the two houses behind the trees.

  [image: screenshot]
- After the screen flashes, hit the ball to the tiny circle of trees.
- After the screen flashes again, sink the ball in the hole behind the tiny house next to the water.

### Paris Rooftops • Paris, France

**Hole 10 (*FLVCTVAT NEC MERGITVR*)**

- Found on Hole 11 (Déjà vu)
- Hidden underneath a hedge on the ledge near the tee.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Déjà vu*)**

- Found on Hole 7
- Hidden in the trees next to the 4 water puddles.

  [image: screenshot]

### Kaski Pass • Grandaki, Nepal

**Hole 10 (*Base Camp*)**

- Found on Hole 6
- Look left of the tee in the canyon with the river. The hole is on the beach near the edge of the map.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Yakkity Yak*)**

- Found on Hole 3
- Out of bounds at the base of the cliff in back right of the map.

  [image: screenshot]

### Hallows Creek • Colorado, USA

**Hole 10 (*Maze of Scarecrows*)**

- Found on Hole 7
- Located in the right corner of the map in a patch of rough behind the hay, near the scarecrow.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Ruins of Despair*)**

- Found on Hole 10 (*Maze of Scarecrows*)
- Hidden in the trees behind the green in the back corner of the map.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 12 (*The Hole Truth*)**

- Unlocked after smashing 50 green pumpkins hidden throughout the game.

  - For more information, see [*Where are the green pumpkins located?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322443/181240)

### Juovlastállu Park • Lapland

**Hole 10 (*Gift Bag*)**

- Found on Hole 6
- Next to the sled near the green. Between two trees.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 11 (*Yule Log*)**

- Found on Hole 9
- Underneath a Santa hat on a stick by the White House.

  [image: screenshot]

**Hole 12 (*Icebergs Ahead!*)**

- Unlocked after collecting 50 gifts throughout the game.

  - For more information, see [*Where are the 50 hidden gifts located*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/323059/181240)

---

#### Sources

- [Touch Arcade Forums - OK Golf](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=301156)

  - Special thanks to JimJam for [finding](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=3998061&postcount=199) [several](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=4008891&postcount=228) [secret](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=4026742&postcount=267) [holes](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=4037724&postcount=277)
  - Also thanks to [ColbaltZenroni](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=3978203&postcount=57), [iAboabat](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=3980683&postcount=94), [Jstnln](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=3980705&postcount=95), & [arilev](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?p=3997380&postcount=190)

Comment: Looking forward to an update, the new Egypt course has ~5 hidden holes! :D

Comment: @Rawling I haven’t played OK Golf since writing this guide. Feel free to submit an edit with any secret holes that have been added.

Answer (score 3):

When playing Egypt 4 of the 5 hidden holes can be accessed via holes 6 and 8.

[image: 6th Hole]
[image: 8th Hole]

Answer (score 1):

### Greatest Hits

**Hole 4**: in the tiny islands

[image: Hole 4 secret hole]

**Hole 10, Lua Pele**

[image: Hole 10 secret hole]

### Nefertari Oasis

The last secret hole is unlocked by collecting bright blue Anubis statues. And it's worth the effort. Some are hidden in the first four secret holes. Hit your ball at anything that stands out. Once a statue appears, hit your ball at it to collect it. The remaining statues are hidden in holes 3, 4, 5, 7, and 8. One is out in the open. The others have to be revealed by finding and breaking open canopic jars that have dog faces and ears.

[image: Canopic jar with Anubis head]

### Llyncapel Ruins

**Hole 4**: Look for a series of islands past the hole. Find this small patch of fairway to get started.

[image: Small patch of fairway]

Then, continue to the hole

[image: Secret hole]

**Hole 5**: Next to the big tree in the center of the map

[image: Secret hole]

### Tranquility Base: Moon

**Hole 9**: On an asteroid past the green. To reach it, you can put your ball in the far corner of the patch of fairway closest to the asteroid, then start a power shot. Wait until the power shot wobbles closest to you, then release.

[image: Secret hole]

**Hole 10: Sea of Tranquility and another hole**: Look for these big astronauts tumbling through the thin lunar atmosphere. Hit them both to collect them and unlock the final hole.

[image: Secret hole]

Comment: I can only find one astronaut in the air in Hole 10 of Tranquility Base. Where's the other one?

Answer (score 1):

-Llyncapel Ruins-
Carmarthen, Wales

Hole 10 (The Sword)-
Found on Hole 4; on 4th. island to left side of map in front of headstone.

Hole 11 (Cataclysm)-
Found on Hole 5; at base of large headstone in the center of map.