# Where are the hidden gifts located?

Tags: ok-golf

OK Golf's 1.82 update has added 50 collectable green gifts to courses throughout the game.

> GIFT HUNT - Find all the hidden gifts to unlock a secret area!

[Just like the previous Pumpkin Hunt event](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322442/181240), collecting all 50 gifts will presumably unlock a secret hole for the new winter course, *Juovlastállu Park - Lapland*.

Where are the 50 hidden gifts located? What holes are they on?

[image: counter for hidden gifts]

Comment: If you need assistance locating a specific gift then we can help with that but looking for a guide to find all 50 is too board for our format. There are plenty of places out there that offer that sort of guide.

Comment: @Colin This is a self-answered question. I’ve listed all 50 locations below as a guide for others. Currently there aren’t any other guides online for this.

Comment: The answer took you 818 words and 50 images, if that's not too broad then I don't know what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listed below are the locations for <s>50</s> *51* hidden gifts in OK Golf. I've included a screenshot for each.

**Notes**

- You can toggle between hunting for hidden gifts or green pumpkins in the options. (See [*Where are the green pumpkins located?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322442/181240))
- Thanks to [JimJam on the Touch Arcade forums](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=301156&page=39) for pointing out several gifts I missed.
- There is an extra 51<sup>th</sup> hidden gift, making it possible to collect 51/50 gifts.

## Hidden gift locations in OK Golf

#### Long Lake County • Georgia, USA

- **Hole 1:** [On the fairway to the left of the lone tree in the rough.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMvzp.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [In the trees next to the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW3JT.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [Behind a small rock straight forward from the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVfbf.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [In the rough in the right-corner of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61FcP.jpg)
- **Hole 8:** [Hidden in the trees between the starting tee and the green. Look near the white out-of-bounds void.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw9Zw.jpg)

#### Desert Canyon • Arizona, USA

- **Hole 2:** [By a tall cactus to the left of the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBhCA.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [In the water next to a cactus near the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/921gG.jpg)
- **Hole 8:** [Behind a cactus in the rough to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i618F.jpg)
- **Hole 11 (*Nice View Up Here*):** [On the green on top of the big hill.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H8NK.jpg)

#### Tsukimi Garden • Kyoto, Japan

- **Hole 1:** [In the right corner of the map in the trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVHhT.jpg)
- **Hole 2:** [In the pond to the left of the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6hFy.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [In between two trees near the water in the right corner of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5kjb.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [Under a pink tree in the center of the map. In between the two ponds.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yitpm.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*Long Way Round*):** [Look past the lake and to the right. It's under the trees in between the two fairway sections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0S8j.jpg)

#### Pahoehoe Ridge • Hawaii, USA

- **Hole 2:** [Underneath a small tree on the second path of fairway. Look nearby the two rocks in the water.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yLiC.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [Hidden under a small tree near the green in the left corner of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0537.jpg)
- **Hole 8:** [In a patch of water by two rocks near the near a small tree and two palm trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gswe2.jpg) (*May take several attempts*)
- **Hole 11: (*Abandoned Course*):** [In the rough across from the tee in the back-left corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKJt2.jpg)
- **Hole 11: (*Abandoned Course*):** [A second gift is down one of the water-holes near the back-left corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9EH5.jpg)

#### Buchan Bay • Aberdeen, Scotland

- **Hole 1:** [To the right of the green in the rough.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sVwF.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [Behind the tower near the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zs2s.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [In the ruins to the right of the green near the water.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxZrY.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [On top of a tower to the right of the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZYhg.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [Perched on the ruins to the left of the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjpAo.jpg)
- **Hole 11 (*Fort Fore*):** [In the water next to submerged ruins, by a tiny beach near the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AWJk.jpg)

#### Miami Palms • Florida, USA

- **Hole 1:** [In the rough by some palm trees to the left of the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bv0p.jpg)
- **Hole 2:** [In the rough behind a tree, to the right of the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Ipa.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [Submerged in the water to the right of the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sacU.jpg)
- **Hole 8:** [In the white out-of-bounds void behind the starting tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJYAe.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*Omega Golf*):** [In the rough behind the skyscraper.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXV7I.jpg)

#### Oakford Woods • Somerset, England

- **Hole 4:** [On top of the red chimney of the house in the trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB18g.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [In the left corner of the map behind some trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz7Mq.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [Behind the third house in the trees on the edge of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2ZP1.jpg)
- **Hole 8:** [In the rough behind the trees to the left of the tee.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfpeo.jpg)
- **Hole 10 (*The Storm*):** [On a small, square island of rough towards the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOG70.jpg)

#### Paris Rooftops • Paris, France

- **Hole 1:** [Behind the starting tee near the roof's edge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSV7.jpg)
- **Hole 5:** [On a windowsill in between the second and third building.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2l8r.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [In between two chimneys next to the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InSY3.jpg)
- **Hole 11 (*Déjà vu*):** [Flat on the ground to the right of the tee. Clips through the floor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3mDr.jpg)

#### Kaski Pass • Grandaki, Nepal

- **Hole 3:** [Next to the statue with multicolored flags, on top of the hill near the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGiQ4.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [Behind the statue with multicolored flags.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkDXx.jpg)
- **Hole 6:** [Down in the ravine by the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2SSU.jpg)

#### Hallows Creek • Colorado, USA

- **Hole 4:** [In a group of trees near the pumpkin patch in the back-left of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOfLM.jpg)
- **Hole 7:** [Held by a scarecrow behind hay bales in the right corner of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDDDD.jpg)
- **Hole 12 (*The Hole Truth*):** [Next to the bat statue and glowing jack-o-lantern in the center of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86RQ7.jpg)

#### Juovlastállu Park • Lapland

- **Hole 1:** [Directly next to the starting tee under a bulletin board.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQvz.jpg)
- **Hole 2:** [In a sleigh by the snowman near the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RauxG.jpg)
- **Hole 3:** [By the door of a white house near the green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o0io.jpg)
- **Hole 4:** [In a small hole in the ice near a sled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9hcR.jpg)
- **Hole 9:** [On the green next to other gifts, near a wood cabin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXjsD.jpg)
- **Hole 11 (*Yule Log*):** [Under the Christmas tree in the center of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWMVj.jpg)

---